# How do I change a SharePoint 2010 project with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to change an existing SharePoint 2010 project through altering C# files in Visual Studio 2022.

However, I always get the following error whenever I try to build or compile the project:

```
The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: You do know that SharePoint 2010 has been out of support for nearly 2 years now?

Comment: Yes, I do know but sadly the company I work at still uses it.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What .NET framework are you targeting? Is development being done on your local PC and deployed to the SharePoint server? Do you have code you can share? Not having done any SharePoint dev myself, I do suspect you would need some SharePoint libraries installed for your code to reference (probably very hard to find 2010 versions though).

Comment: I don't know the .net framework I am targetting. I am getting a copy of the project from server. I can't share the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since SharePoint 2010 is out of support, I will recommend you to migrate to SharePoint 2013. Please refer to the following document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/overview-of-the-upgrade-process-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013